# jquery keypress not working after load?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a navigation using the keyboard. I load new content with jquerys load() function but it only works the first time the script is loaded, I've heard that you're supposed to use jquery live() function to get it to load every page but it doesn't.
This is the keypress function:

```
$(document).live("keydown", function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 49) {
            $('.next').click();
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 50) {
            $('.prev').click();
        }
    });
```

This code is in every page that gets loaded. But only works the first time you use the page, after one click, it doesn't work. Why? What .next and .prev do:

```
$('.next').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var href = this.href;
        $('.loading').fadeIn();
        $('#content').load(href, function(){ 
            $('.loading').fadeOut();
        });
    });
```

It does however work to press .next and .prev after load with your mouse all the time. Just the keypress that only works once.

This is the HTML structure:

```
<div id="content">
 Image
 <div class="nav">
  <a href="page.php?id=1" class="prev">Prev</a>
  <a href="page.php?id=2" class="next">Next</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does clicking `.next` and `.prev` do?

Comment: Edited top post with .next

Comment: Are you sure the anchor isn't being followed by the browser? Does the URL in the address bar show `page.php?id=1`?

Comment: No it doesen't, it loads the next page without refreshing browser window

Comment: Is this button `$('.next')` inside your dynamically loaded content?

Comment: Yes, as displayed above in the html, the whole #content is being reloaded. With new .next buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this will work for you.

```
$('.next').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var href = this.href;
  $('.loading').fadeIn();
  $('.main-bg').load(href, function () {
    $('.loading').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Since you need those two buttons always, you don't need to load them dynamically. Also the the number of events will increase with each click. So replace only the content inside `main-bg` div.

**Update:**

Also, I have noticed that you are re-loading the javascript whenever you change the image. That will create issues. So add script to the first page only.

If you want the script to be loaded each time, then use the following code

```
$(document).keydown( function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 49) {
            $('.next').click();
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 50) {
            $('.prev').click();
        }
    });

$('.next').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var href = this.href;
        $('.loading').fadeIn();
        $('#content').load(href, function(){ 
            $('.loading').fadeOut();
        });
    });
```

Comment: But i do need to replace those buttons href. Cause the href change and thats why i reload the whole thing but i could program me around this if there is no solution to make this work otherwise.

Comment: Check my updated answer. It is a major issue. Number of events will increase with each click.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 49) {
        $('.next').trigger("click");
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 50) {
        $('.prev').trigger("click");
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '.next', function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $('.loading').fadeIn();
    $('#content').load(href, function(){ 
        $('.loading').fadeOut();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Please do check, #content is unique after loading the content... I changed some of your code but it's not necessary I think.

Comment: The same thing happens with this as it does with mine, works first time not after load, updated my original post with what .next and .prev does if that makes a difference?

Comment: `.trigger("click")` is the same as `.click()` called with no parameters. From http://api.jquery.com/click/ "_In the third variation, when .click() is called without arguments, it is a shortcut for .trigger("click")._"

Comment: I edited my answer. You're true j08691, it just seems to me cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what do you mean #content should be unique? Maybe that could be a problem?

Comment: an id has to be unique. You can use it just one time: http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20/tests/test185.html. If you can't use a class like (".content") or make ids like that : ("#content1", "#content2"). If you load a page wich has the id="content" inside it, your code won't work. I don't know if I am clear enough.

Comment: You are clear enough but this isn't the case, it is unique. You can check out the html structure i've edited in my top post, the page loads a new .prev and a new .next every reload. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Maybe html encoding issues, no? The simplest thing is to put your nav outside of the div which has the id="content". Is it working now?

Comment: Tried it and no it doesen't :(

Comment: Actually this is working for me in localhost, check any output of console with firebug or the inspector of Chrome. This is really strange... Don't you have a 500 error when trying to load the second page?